# Consuming SAP web-service from .NET throws exception ServiceModel.FaultException

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I reference the WSDL file and make a request to the SAP web-service and get the exception below

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Server Error Server stack trace: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) Exception rethrown at [0]:
>
> at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>
> at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)

I can consume the web service via WSDL from SOAPUI.

Also I have set the following binding properties.

```
 var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding
        {
            SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue,
            CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
            OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
            ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
            MaxBufferPoolSize = Int64.MaxValue
            
        };
```

I trace the visual studio request from fiddler and can execute the same request from SoapUI, but while trying to consume through Visual Studio, the exception occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually started from scratch and solved the problem.

The response was over 8mb and request was taking over 100 seconds.

I made the following changes in the config file and the problem was solved.

```
    <binding receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00"
openTimeout="00:05:00"  closeTimeout="00:05:00"
maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"  maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" >
<readerQuotas maxDepth="20000000"
                            maxStringContentLength="20000000"
                            maxArrayLength="20000000"
                            maxBytesPerRead="20000000"
                            maxNameTableCharCount="20000000" />
   ....
```